# Check duplicate entries with different foreign keys id in the same table in where clause

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

I have a table where there is a columns `id,name and externalid(FK)`. The name can repeat but only if the externalid is different. How can i find out the number of count for the name column greater than 1 but externalid's are different. I have tried the following query. But I am not sure with the results. Please correct my query if its wrong.

```
SELECT  ff.Name , COUNT(*) count FROM tablee ff
join tablee f on ff.ID = f.ID
where f.externalid=ff.externalid
GROUP BY  ff.Name Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to change your `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    ff.Name,
    COUNT(*) count
FROM tablee ff
INNER JOIN tablee f
    ON ff.ID = f.ID AND
       f.externalid = ff.externalid
GROUP BY
    ff.Name
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT ff.externalid) = COUNT(*) AND
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This `HAVING` clause will return true only when the number of distinct external IDs equals the number of times a name appears in each name group.  This implies that every external ID is unique for that name group.

Note that I also moved the logic of the `WHERE` clause into the join condition.  This looks cleaner to me and I don't know why you had that logic in the `WHERE` clause.